# I can't access the first object in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried to follow other guides, but none seems to be working. I want to get the first object in a separate JSON file that looks like this (snippet):

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "occupation": "cook",
        "id": [{
            "address": {
                "postal_code": 12342,
                "city": "detroit"
              },
              "children": "none"
        ],
}
}
            // and so forth, there are more objects in the employees-array
```

My code snippet looks like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.employees, function(i, emp) {
        if (this.id.length) {
            console.log(this[0].address.city);
        }
    }
```

I want to access the first object's "address". If I type `console.log(this.address[0].city);, i'll get all first "city"-values from every object in "employees".

Thanks in beforehand!

Comment: You have missed out the `id` property.

Comment: Sorry, I renamed the variables when uploading the question and forgot that particular one. Has been edited.

Comment: You are using `$.each` loop that goes through all the objects. If you only want the first one use `employees[0].id[0].city` - if I understand the problem right

Comment: Correct, I only want the first "city" within the first "id"-object. There are multiple "id"-objects in the "employees"-array.

Comment: If you had said that you want the first city from the first id of the first employee from the start you would have saved a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem, and based on the comment of @Velimir Tchatchevsky I think what you want is:

```
data.employees[0].id[0].address.city
```

[jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/kimaescobar/L7czwg8s/)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it! Thank you all very much for your efforts! :)

Answer (score 4):

Inside the `each()`, `this` will refer to the `employee` object, so you need to amend the `console.log()` to this:

```
$.each(data.employees, function(i, emp) {
    if (this.id.length) {
        console.log(this.id[0].address.city);
    }
});
```

Comment: I also tried that, but I'm still getting all "city"-values from every object in "employees".

Comment: As you can see from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mk61k8c/1/) the above definitely works, even with multiple objects in the `id` array.

Answer (score 3):

Why do not you use emp variable in each block?

```
$.each(data.employees, function(i, emp) {
    if (emp.id.length) {
        console.log(emp.id[0].address.city);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check with if(emp.id[0]) instead of emp.id.length (if I want to access emp.id[0])

Answer (score 1):

Initially your object is

```
{
    "employees": [{
        "occupation": "cook",
        "id": [{
            "address": {
                "postal_code": 12342,
                "city": "detroit"
              },
              "children": "none"
        ],
}
}
```

> try this code.

```
  $.each(data.employees, function(i, emp) { //each function will able access each employees
    if (this.id.length) {
        console.log(this.id[0].address.city); // at each employee get the first element of array id.
    }
}
```

1. `.each` function will go through out the `employees` array.
2. `this.id[0]` this will able access the first element of array identified as a id. inside id there is a address object.

   ```
              "address": {
                   "postal_code": 12342,
                   "city": "detroit"
                 }
   ```
3. `this.id[0].address` :- this code will give you the address object.

   ```
                {
                   "postal_code": 12342,
                   "city": "detroit"
                 }
   ```
4. `this.id[0].address.city` :- Inside address object you will get the city now using this piece of code. Here you will got your Answer..

   ```
   "city": "detroit"
   ```

Thanks.